# Flutter: Add new pages in pageview while swiping

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How is it possible to add new page in pageview widget while I am swiping ?
I tried to setstate after animation and adding new page in list but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<String> _list = ['test', 'test', 'test'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TabBar Demo'),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          _list.add('test');
          setState(() {});
        },
        itemCount: _list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                _list[index],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
    }
    
    class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      PageController _pageController = PageController(
        initialPage: 0,
      );
      int currentIndex = 0;
    
      Widget childWidget = ChildWidget(
        number: AvailableNumber.First,
      );
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _pageController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[500],
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: (value) {
              currentIndex = value;
              _pageController.animateToPage(
                value,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                curve: Curves.linear,
              );
    
              setState(() {});
            },
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text("First"),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                title: Text("Second"),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                title: Text("Third"),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                title: Text("Third"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = page;
              });
            },
            children: <Widget>[
             Text('1'),
               Text(2'),
                    Text('3'),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[video example](https://youtu.be/3aChah4Fyak)